# Promise - это реализация шаблона проектирования или импровизация?

Tags: javascript, шаблоны-проектирования

Изучая код **Promise** я столкнулся со сложность интерпретации кода, как шаблона проектирования.
И от сюда вопрос - **promise**, это реализация какого-то паттерна или импровизация автора?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Это открытый стандарт: http://promisesaplus.com/
2. Паттерн: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises

Comment: И ещё:

 - http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-dom-20131107/#promises
 - https://github.com/domenic/promises-unwrapping/blob/master/docs/writing-specifications-with-promises.md

Comment: «Чистой» реализации нет :] Но есть стандарт, как должны работать «Обещания» и какое API предоставлять. Нативно поддерживается только Chrome и FF, для остальных полифилы или подобные либы, коих море:

 - Polyfill — https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise
 - Либы: [Q][1], [when][2], [JDeferred][3] и т.п.

[1]: https://github.com/kriskowal/q
[2]: https://github.com/cujojs/when
[3]: https://github.com/jdeferred/jdeferred

Comment: Есть стандарт Promise/A+, там описано, как должны вести себя общения и есть кучи библиотек, которые дают 
это поведение, но вот конечная реализация и API, которое они предлагают могут быть разными. Есть реализация от jQuery (которая кстати не проходит Promise/A+), в [браузерах][1] своя реализация, но с единым  API, которое описано на w3c. 

В целом не понятно, причем тут «посмотреть реализацию передачи значений от метода к методу» и собственно сами «Общения»

[1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: @vas посмотреть реализацию значит [вот что](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)

Comment: Реализацию чего именно? Самих обещаний или как ими пользоваться? Выше я давал ссылку по [полифил][1], это одна из реализация нативных обезаний, вот например [моя реализация][2], совместимая с jQuery и нативными обещаниями.

[1]: https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise
[2]: https://gist.github.com/RubaXa/8501359

Comment: @vas понизьте слово "паттерн" до "приём" и все встанет на свои места.